# for loop through enumerated type in C raising compilation error

Tags: c, compiler-errors, post-increment, postfix-operator, enumerated-types

I have a code that defines a simple enumerated type, then loop through it to print the corresponding syllable.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef enum syllable
{
  Do=1, Re=2, Mi=3, Fa=4, So=5, La=6, Ti=7
} Syllable;

void Sound(Syllable sy)
{
  switch (sy)
  {
    case Do:
      puts("Do"); return;
    case Re:
      puts("Re"); return;
    case Mi:
      puts("Mi"); return;
    case Fa:
      puts("Fa"); return;
    case So:
      puts("So"); return;
    case La:
      puts("La"); return;
    case Ti:
      puts("Ti"); return;
  }
  puts("Sing together~");
}

int main(void)
{
  Syllable tone;
  for (tone=Do; tone<Ti; tone++)
    Sound(tone);
  
  return 0;
}
```

However, this code is raising error `no 'operator++(int)' declared for postfix '++' [-fpermissive]` on compilation at line `tone++`. What am I doing wrong here, and how can I fix it such that I can loop through Syllable correctly?

Comment: That is a C++ error message. Did you intend to compile your code as C++ and not C?

Comment: you can't do a postfix 'in C++) on an enum. Here simply use prefix in place: ++tone, or compile as C.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I compiled the code on Visual Studio Code with C/C++: g++.exe build.

Comment: So you used a C++ compiler.  Use a C compiler (i.e. gcc) to compile C code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are compiling your code as a C++ code.

From the C++14 Standard (5.2.6 Increment and decrement)

> 1 The value of a postfix ++ expression is the value of its operand. [
> Note: the value obtained is a copy of the original value — end note ]
> The operand shall be a modifiable lvalue. The type of the operand
> shall be an **arithmetic type** or a pointer to a complete object
> type.

and (3.9.1 Fundamental types)

> 7 Types bool, char, char16_t, char32_t, wchar_t, and the signed and
> unsigned integer types are collectively called integral types.

and

> 8 There are three floating point types: float, double, and long
> double. The type double provides at least as much precision as float,
> and the type long double provides at least as much precision as
> double. The set of values of the type float is a subset of the set of
> values of the type double; the set of values of the type double is a
> subset of the set of values of the type long double. The value
> representation of floating-point types is implementation-defined.
> **Integral and floating types are collectively called arithmetic types.** Specializations of the standard template std::numeric_limits
> (18.3) shall specify the maximum and minimum values of each arithmetic
> type for an implementation

As you can see enumerations are not included in the arithmetic types in C++. So the postfix increment operator for enumerations is not defined in C++.

On the other hand, in C (The C Standard (6.5.2.4 Postfix increment and decrement operators)

> Constraints
>
> 1 **The operand of the postfix increment or decrement operator shall
> have atomic, qualified, or unqualified real** or pointer type, and shall
> be a modifiable lvalue.

and (6.2.5 Types)

> 17 T**he type char, the signed and unsigned integer types, and the
> enumerated types are collectively called integer types. The integer
> and real floating types are collectively called real types.**

In C enumerations are included in the family of integer types and correspondingly in the family of real types for which the postfix increment operators is defined.

So compile your code as a C code.

In C++ you need explicitly to overload the postfix increment operator as a user-defined function something like

```
Syllable operator ++( Syllable &e, int )
{
    Syllable tmp = e == Ti ? Do : static_cast<Syllable>( e  + 1 );

    e = e == Ti ? Do : static_cast<Syllable>( e + 1 );

    return tmp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Enum Class or just compile as C. build with gcc

If you use VScode, use Code-Runner Extention will be helpful.

try `$gcc {filename} -o {outfilename}`

Answer (score 0):

Use a compiler which allows you to compile in C, You can try it on varous online compilers also.

Comment: the accepted answer provides far more useful info